# Why doesn't @Stepwise work across class boundaries when using inheritance in a Geb test using Spock?

Tags: inheritance, functional-testing, spock, geb

While it may not be the best method, using inheritance to compose a suite of Geb tests (using Spock) is fairly common.

Using `@Stepwise` is critical to making this work but it doesn't seem to work across class boundaries as shown in this image:

[image: Image showing Stepwise not operating as expected]

I have a hack solution in place to get around this, but would really like to know if this is expected behavior or a bug that Geb or Spock should be looking into.

Comment: Why is using `@Stepwise` better than building a library of reusable higher-level functions that you can use in multiple tests? Sure it may be slower to execute once, but I guarantee it's faster when you get failures that stop the entire suite when using `@Stepwise`.

Comment: I have grown accustomed to using `@Stepwise` to build up a collection of moderate/short hierarchies of tests that start with user creation/registration and get quickly to the heart of the matter. I have recently been putting more and more behavior into the `Page` (and now `Module`s) and really like how it is shaping up. Until we can solve the data setup problems we will still rely on inheritance to build my test trees. I'm working on a thorough description and question about best practice. It will likely be posted early next week.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The stepwise annotation works only for a single spec. It was never intended to span across classes or across hierachies (a popular request in the Spock mailing list).

It says right so in the official Javadoc (emphasis mine):

> Indicates that a spec's feature methods should be run sequentially in
>   their declared order (even in the presence of a parallel spec runner),
>   always starting from the first method. If a method fails, the
>   remaining methods will be skipped. **Feature methods declared in super-
>   and subspecs are not affected**

http://spockframework.github.io/spock/javadoc/1.0/spock/lang/Stepwise.html

Answering your original question: this is expected behavior